# AudioKit AKMusicTrack not playing MIDI

Tags: swift, audiokit

So I have a AKMusicTrack which gets populated with AKMIDINotes whenever someone is playing the AKKeyboard.

The problem that I'm currently facing is that if an AKMIDINote of the same note is added to the AKMusicTrack with similarities in position and duration then only one will play. Let me clarify the issue a bit more, lets say I have two notes 74 & 74 and the second 74 is supposed to play whilst the first 74 is still playing, it won't.

Here's an example of an array of AKMIDINoteData from the AKMusicTrack where the second note doesn't play:

```
[note: 74 velocity: 127 chan: 0 duration: 1.31484985351562 position 0.663384547,
note: 74 velocity: 127 chan: 0 duration: 1.68195784091949 position 1.09386738]
```

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but would really love to see a sample project exhibiting this behavior. Can you share one either publicly or privately?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Can I share it with you privately? How would you like for me to that?

Comment: Dropbox or GitHub

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Thanks for offering help but I've fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to format it a specific way:

```
.replaceMIDINoteData(with: [AKMIDINoteData(noteNumber: 14, velocity: 75, channel: 0, duration: AKDuration(beats: 1.31484985351562), position: AKDuration(beats: 1.0))])
```